# How to count document requests in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have a single-page application running in the browser, served locally by Firebase Emulators. It fetches documents from Firestore.

Is there a way to see/count how many documents and/or collections were requested when I open the page?

I would like to know how much opening this page will cost me.

I can not add counters to my code, because this would require deep knowledge of how the Firestore client library works.

Example 1: When my App has two components on a page. And both components subscribe to the same document. Do I have to count 2 loaded documents (because I requested the document twice)? Or do I have to count only 1 (because the Firestore library reuses the subscription from the first component)?

Example 2: When I have a subscription to a query that loads 10 documents. And another subscription to another query that loads 10 documents. But there is an overlap of 5 documents that are returned in both subscriptions. Do I have to pay for 20 documents or just for 15?

Could I perhaps somehow interpret the network traffic in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: This seems like something you could do with your own logging in the application associated with each query you make. I don't think anything is going to count this for you, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I can only put logging into my code. But not into the firestore lib. And only the firestore lib knows when it requests documents. For example: When I have two components on my page. And both subscribe to the same document? Did I request 1 document or 2 documents? The firestore lib could be implemented in a simple way where it subscribes two times to the same document. Or in an intelligent way where it reuses the first subscription for the second one. How can I know?

Comment: Or you could write an abstraction layer around the Firestore SDK to count all the documents it receives without worrying about duplicates. As long as all of your app code is using the abstraction, it doesn't matter what any of it does - the abstraction will intercept everything reliably.

Comment: How can I add an abstraction layer between Google's client lib and the server?

Comment: Writing that is very much non-trivial and beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing when it comes to Firestore is that you're **always** charged for reads that happen on the server. That's it.

> When my App has two components on a page. And both components subscribe to the same document. Do I have to count 2 loaded documents (because I requested the document twice)? Or do I have to count only 1 (because the Firestore library reuses the subscription from the first component)?

If you're attaching two [real-time listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), on the exact same document, one of the listeners will read the data from the server, while the second one will be able to read the data from the cache.

On the other hand, if you're using [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) instead of using listeners, the result is totally different. This means that you'll have to pay for two document reads. Why is this happening? It's because when there are no active listeners, the client SDK doesn't know if the document is changed or not between the two calls. This also means that it will have to check with the server whether there are updates or not. So these operations result in charged reads.

> When I have a subscription to a query that loads 10 documents. And another subscription to another query that loads 10 documents. But there is an overlap of 5 documents that are returned in both subscriptions. Do I have to pay for 20 documents or just for 15?

The above explanation is available in the case of queries too. If you're using real-time listeners, you'll have to pay 10 reads for the first query, and only 5 more reads for the second one. Why? Because the other 5 documents can be read from the cache. Cache reads have no costs.

Besides that, I think that the following resource will also help:

- [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e)

Comment: Hey Witek. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like

```js
        const filesCollection = collection(db, "somecollection");
        const filesQuery = query(filesCollection);
        const snapshot = await getDocs(filesQuery);
        
        const queryCount = snapshot.docs.length; 
        console.log(`Number of queries: ${queryCount}`);
        
        const filesData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
          return {
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
          } as SomeInterface;
        });
        setState(filesData); etc, etc
```

This returned `Number of queries: 17` for me tested in a firebase/firestore app I have running.

EDIT: I saw your comment, and I think I see what you mean. What I do is make sure that I query my database once (much like above), and then essentially cache it in some state variables of type interface[]. Then all my other functions/componenets that "query" for some info, are really just looking through the cached data, until there is some addition/edit to the database, in which case I call the function that re-fetches the data and updates the cache. I hope this helps, but I don't understand really what you mean by you cannot edit your firebase code.

Comment: So you assume that the Firebase client lib is very stupid and does not reuse subscriptions. Do you know this for a fact?

Comment: All I know is that firebase doesn't have much motivation to not charge me for extra reads, and somehow I doubt that it implements caching on its own without explicitly calling for it. I don't think its too much work to query the data and locally cache it, instead of assuming that firebase wants to save you money.

Comment: Exactly. Assuming it would be stupid. That's why I am asking here. Would be nice if someone knew the answer.